# How to access inner html element present in actual html via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the object of second level html element in my page.

```
<html>
<div id="out">
jasoidjisa
    <html>
        <head>//This object
        <div id="in">
          hihisdhi  
        </div>
        </head>
    </html>
</div>
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html'));
</script>
```

Help me to access this html element via js

Comment: html is reserved tagname that specifies html document. You should use some other tagname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is a reserved tag name and so you can't use it in the manner in which you have used it here. Which particular value from above are you trying to get exactly ? It might make sense to use the `<div>` tag with a class or I'd to identify it instead. If you specify which value you are specifically looking to get I can write up a theoretical solution.

Answer (score 0):

vsank7787 was totally correct. Maybe you could use iFrames instead of nested html inside a HTML document since html is a reserved keyword.